# R: take first 13 characters from a string, concatenate with other strings

Tags: r, split, character, concatenation

I have a data frame `df` with three columns `ref`, `driver` and `tour`.

```
                                      ref      driver       tour
    02062018-1130SGA->BRT-Buttes Chaumont        Mark         NA
02162018-1230BRT-A2Pas Courbevoie Marceau        John         NA
          02067018-1300SGA->BRT-Brune 2/2         Sam         NA
             020718-0800-CHILLY-CHARENTON      Claire        678
           020718-0800-CHILLY-BATIGNOLLES          NA         NA
```

I want to mutate a new column `ID` where if `tour` is NA, it concatenates the first 13 letters of `ref` and `driver`. If tour is not NA, it just returns the same value in `tour`. So the result should look like this:

```
                                      ref      driver       tour                  ID
    02062018-1130SGA->BRT-Buttes Chaumont        Mark         NA   02062018-1130Mark
02162018-1230BRT-A2Pas Courbevoie Marceau        John         NA   02162018-1230John
          02067018-1300SGA->BRT-Brune 2/2         Sam         NA    02067018-1300Sam
             020718-0800-CHILLY-CHARENTON      Claire        678                 678
           020718-0800-CHILLY-BATIGNOLLES          NA         NA       020718-0800-C
```

Note that if `driver`column is also `NA`, I don't want to take `NA` as a character but instead I just want to return the first 13 characters from `ref`.

My idea is to use `ifelse` function, but just don't know how to work around taking the first 13 letters and concatenating to `Driver`.

```
df$ID <- ifelse(tour == NA, 
                yes = #####some function######, 
                no = tour)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `substr` in combination with `paste0`.

```
df1$ID <- ifelse(is.na(df1$tour), 
            paste0(substr(df1$ref, 1, 13), ifelse(is.na(df1$driver), "", df1$driver)), 
              df1$tour)

 "02062018-1130Mark" "02162018-1230John" "02067018-1300Sam"  "678"  "020718-0800-C"
```

Comment: thank you very much for your quick answer! When the driver column is `NA`, it takes `NA` as a character and the result looks like "02162018-1230NA". but I just want "02162018-1230" without `NA`. How should I deal with this? Sorry I should have been clearer about this.

Comment: I edited my answer. Added an extra ifelse in the code